# XML serialization, encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, xml-serialization

```
using System;

public class clsPerson
{
  public  string FirstName;
  public  string MI;
  public  string LastName;
}

class class1
{ 
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      clsPerson p=new clsPerson();
      p.FirstName = "Jeff";
      p.MI = "A";
      p.LastName = "Price";
      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p.GetType());
      x.Serialize(Console.Out, p);
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

taken from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813

1)

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p.GetType());
```

What does this line do? what is GetType()?

2) how do I get the encoding to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
< clsPerson xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

instead of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM437"?>
 <clsPerson xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3
 .org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

or not include the encoding type at all?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1) The GetType() function returns a Type object representing the type of your object, in this case the class `clsPerson`. You could also use `typeof(clsPerson)` and get the same result. That line creates an XmlSerializer object for your particular class.

2) If you want to change the encoding, I believe there is an override of the Serialize() function that lets you specify that. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8x4k1h2.aspx) for details. You may have to create an XmlWriter object to use it though, details for that are also on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx):

```
 XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, settings);
```

You can also set the encoding in the XmlWriter, the XmlWriterSettings object has an Encoding property.

Answer (score 63):

If you pass the serializer an XmlWriter, you can control some parameters like encoding, whether to omit the declaration (eg for a fragment), etc.

This is not meant to be a definitive guide, but an alternative so you can see what's going on, and something that isn't just going to console first.

Note also, if you create your XmlWriter with a StringBuilder instead of a MemoryStream, your xml will ignore your Encoding and come out as utf-16 encoded. See the blog post [writing xml with utf8 encoding](http://devproj20.blogspot.com/2008/02/writing-xml-with-utf-8-encoding-using.html) for more information.

```
XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings 
{ 
    Indent = true, 
    OmitXmlDeclaration = false, 
    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 
};

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream() )
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings))
{   
    var x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p.GetType());
    x.Serialize(xmlWriter, p);

    // we just output back to the console for this demo.
    memoryStream.Position = 0; // rewind the stream before reading back.
    using( StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
    } // note memory stream disposed by StreamReaders Dispose()
}
```

Comment: In this example the StreamReader will close the MemoryStream. The using Dispose of the XmlWriter will then try to access the closed stream. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8833066/28594 for alternate ways to structure the usings.

Comment: Sheesh. Talk about hidden complexity.

Answer (score 3):

I took the solution offered by @robert-paulson here for a similar thing I was trying to do and get the string of an XmlSchema. By default it would return as utf-16.  However as mentioned the solution here suffers from a Stream Closed Read error.  So I tool the liberty of posting the refactor as an extension method with the tweek mentioned by @Liam to move the using block.

```
    public static string ToXmlString(this XmlSchema xsd)
    {
        var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true,
            OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        };

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings))
            {
                xsd.Write(xmlWriter);
            }

            memoryStream.Position = 0; 
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
            {
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1) This creates a XmlSerializer for the class clsPerson.

2) encoding is IBM437 because that is the form for the Console.Out stream.

PS: Hungarian notation is not preferred in C#; just name you class Person.