# c# using + XmlWriter.Create = "Cannot access a closed Stream."

Tags: c#, silverlight, using, xmlwriter

Why this works:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var dummy = new StreamWriter(ms))
    {
        var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
        sw.WriteLine("Hello World");
        sw.Flush();
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(ms))
        {
            ms.Position = 0;
            textBoxExc.Text = rdr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

but this does not work ("Cannot access a closed Stream."):
Only difference is `var dummy = XmlWriter.Create(ms)` instead of `var dummy = new StreamWriter(ms)`

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var dummy = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
    {
        var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
        sw.WriteLine("Hello World");
        sw.Flush();
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(ms))
        {
            ms.Position = 0;
            textBoxExc.Text = rdr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Cannot access a closed Stream.
  ObjectName=""
  StackTrace:
       w System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()
       w System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       w System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.FlushBuffer()
       w System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.Flush()
       w System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.Close()
       w System.Xml.XmlWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       w System.Xml.XmlWriter.Dispose()
       w SerializeTest.MainPage.buttonExc_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       w System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
       w System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
       w System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       w System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
       w MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
  InnerException:
```

Also this does not work (same error):

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.WriteObject(writer, objectToSave);
        writer.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(ms))
        {
            return rdr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Cannot access a closed Stream.
  ObjectName=""
  StackTrace:
       w System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()
       w System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       w System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.FlushBuffer()
       w System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.Flush()
       w System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.Close()
       w System.Xml.XmlWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       w System.Xml.XmlWriter.Dispose()
       w SerializeTest.SerializeToStringTest[T](T objectToSave)
       w SerializeTest.MainPage.button2A_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       w System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
       w System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
       w System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       w System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
       w MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
  InnerException:
```

but this works (only difference is `StreamReader` w/o `using`):

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.WriteObject(writer, objectToSave);
        writer.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;
        StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(ms);
        return rdr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: No repro on Silverlight 4, I didn't expect one.

Comment: You found a good reason to upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you give us the complete stack trace of the exception? My first guess is that the `XmlWriter` still tries to access the stream within the  `Dispose()` method of the `XmlWriter`.

In your second and fourth code example you place the `StreamReader` in a using-block. This causes the invocation of the `Dispose()` method of the `StreamReader` at the end of this block. This method closes both the reader and the underlying stream. After this, the `Dispose()` method of the `XmlWriter` can't access the stream anymore.

**Update:**
Based on the stackstrace it seems I was right. The `Dispose()` method invokes `Close()`, which in turn wants to flush an already closed stream. This looks like a bug since there should be nothing left to flush.

You already gave the solution: don't close the memorystream before the XmlWriter disposes.

(I assume you know that a using-block implicitly disposes the used object, and that disposing a `StreamReader` or `StreamWriter` implicitly disposes (and closes) the underlying stream.)

Answer (score 16):

just move reading from MemoryStream block on one level with writing to it.

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.WriteObject(writer, objectToSave);
        writer.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;        
    }
    using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(ms))
    {
        return rdr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, Had same problem trying to get an XmlSchema to a string. Once I moved that block as illustrated here all was good.

Comment: Worked for .net core too