# Specify encoding XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, export-to-xml

I've a class correctly defined and after serialize it to XML I'm getting no encoding.

How can I define encoding "ISO-8859-1"?

Here's a sample code

```
var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Transacao));
var file = new FileStream(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "transacao.xml"),FileMode.OpenOrCreate);            
xml.Serialize(file, transacao);            
file.Close();
```

Here are the beginning of xml generated

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<requisicao-transacao xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <dados-ec>
    <numero>1048664497</numero>
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928323/xml-serialization-encoding  I'm not sure about the 8859-1 encoding though

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The following should work:

```
var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Transacao));

var fname = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "transacao.xml");
var appendMode = false;
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fname, appendMode, encoding))
{
    xml.Serialize(sw, transacao);
}
```

If you don't mind me asking, why do you need `ISO-8859-1` encoding in particular? You could probably use `UTF-8` or `UTF-16` (they're more commonly recognizable) and get away with it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a StreamWriter with the desired encoding:

```
System.Text.Encoding code = *WhateverYouWant*
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file, code);
```