# Why XDocument encoding type changed while use XDocument's WriteTo method

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have used XDocument to create simple xml document.I have created document with XDocument and XDeclaration.

```
XDocument encodedDoc8 = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
new XElement("Root", "Content"));
```

If i save this document to file means the encoding type is not changed.

```
using (TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\sample.txt", false)){
   encodedDoc8.Save(sw);
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>Content</Root>
```

But,if I use XDocument's WriteTo method to print the xml means encoding type is changed.

```
using (XmlWriter writ = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out))
{
   encodedDoc8.WriteTo(writ);
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM437" standalone="yes"?><Root>Content</Root>
```

Why this happened?.Please update your answers.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML serialization, encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928323/xml-serialization-encoding)

Comment: Because `Console.Out.Encoding` will be IBM437

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlWriter.cs,ed2d6eb1643a2ccd) for `XmlWriter.Create`, the chain of calls would eventually lead to this constructor:

```
public XmlTextWriter(TextWriter w) : this() {
    textWriter = w;
    encoding = w.Encoding;
    xmlEncoder = new XmlTextEncoder(w);
    xmlEncoder.QuoteChar = this.quoteChar;
}
```

The assignment `encoding = w.Encoding` provides an explanation to what is happening in your case: the `Encoding` setting of the `Console.Out` text writer is copied to the `encoding` setting of the newly created `XmlTextWriter`, replacing the encoding that you supplied in the `XDocument`.